# how to add extra meta box or textarea into custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy

trying to create a custom homepage slider and to add "read more" link on images but i couldn't insert extra `meta` boxes or `textarea`s

```
function featured_image_slider() {
$labels = array(
'name' => _x('Sliders', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('Slider', 'post type singular name'),
'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'slider'),
'add_new_item' => __('Add New Slider'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit Slider'),
'new_item' => __('New Slider'),
'all_items' => __('All Sliders'),
'view_item' => __('View Slider'),
'search_items' => __('Search Sliders'),
'not_found' =>  __('No sliders found'),
'not_found_in_trash' => __('No sliders found in Trash'), 
'parent_item_colon' => '',
'menu_name' => __('Sliders')

);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true, 
'show_in_menu' => true, 
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'has_archive' => true, 
'hierarchical' => false,
'menu_position' => null,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', )
); 
register_post_type('slider',$args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'featured_image_slider' );
```

[image]